# list index out of range python txt

Tags: python, list, txt

I have txt file which looks like:

```
New York,cinema,3,02/04/2022
```

But I've got error in list, even if this code works to another txt files without date, what's the problem?

```
def finished_objects():

   file = open("finished_objects.txt", "r",encoding="UTF8")
   lines = file.readlines()
   L = []  # assign empty list with name 'L'
   for line in lines:
       L.append(line.replace("\n", "").split(","))
   file.close()
   for i in range(len(L)):
       print(L[i][0], ":", L[i][1], ". Quantity:", L[i][2], ". Date: ", L[i][3])    
   return L
```

Comment: Works fine for me on the file you provided. Are you sure there are no empty lines in the file?

Comment: @Koterpillar yes, I've got New York,cinema,3,02/04/2022 in it, even when I duplicate diese line to make sure, still error

Comment: Print each `line`, that will most likely show the problem.

Comment: it so strange, but now no error.. hm

Comment: inside this loop ```for line in lines:``` add a statement like this ```if len(line.replace("\n", "").split(",")) == 3```

Comment: Did you try to check the value of `L[i]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use "with" for opening files like,

```
with open("finished_objects.txt", "r",encoding="UTF8") as file:
  lines = file.readlines()
   L = []  # assign empty list with name 'L'
   for line in lines:
       L.append(line.replace("\n", "").split(","))
   # rest of your code
```

That way you don't have to manage the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on my end. Might be that your file has one entry with less commas than others. You could do a simple if `len(L) != 4` inside your last loop to make sure you won't get errors while running.